# What happened to the first 4 terms?

Tags: python

I am actively trying to figure out what happened to the first 4 terms preceding the 5th term and I am trying to display it but my code will only display the 5th term. Any way to fix this?

WANTED Result

[image]

compared to the ACTUAL Result

[image]

```
def e_sin(angle):
    x = angle * math.pi/180
    sum = 0
    n = 0
    sin = math.sin(x)
    error = 10e-13
    while(abs(n - sin) > error):
        n = n+math.pow(-1, sum)* math.pow(x, 2*sum+1)/math.factorial(2*sum+1)
        sum = sum+1
    print("Number of terms: " +str(sum) + " Approximation:" + str(n) +" math.sin(x):" +str(sin))
e_sin(13)
```

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're trying to do here - all 5 look different to me - but maybe it's because you're setting `sin` to a constant value and then never changing it?

Comment: You have to put your print inside the while loop, by adding a tab before the print

Comment: This code won't produce the result show, neither.  There's only one call to `print`, and it's not in the loop. Your "actual" result appears to come from code with 2 loops, each containing a (different) call to `print`.